# Is it possible to setState on other function tag?

Tags: react-native, setstate

Here is my code,

This code is working fine use "setState" to set new variable in componentDidMount tag.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){  
        super(props);  
        this.state = { 
          name: "peter",
        }  
    }
    componentDidMount(){ 
      this.setState({name:"sam"});  
    } 
    render(){
    return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        {this.state.name}
      </Text>
    </View>
    )
   } 
}
```

But I want to create a new function to set it.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){  
        super(props);  
        this.state = { 
          name: "peter",
        }  
    }
    changename(){ 
      this.setState({name:"sam"});  
    } 
    render(){
    this.changename();
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        {this.state.name}
      </Text>
    </View>
    )
   } 
}
```

It displays

```
Minified React error #185;
```

Error

componentDidMount is work,
but it is not working on my own function tag

any idea how to fix it
Thank you very much.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `setState` within `render` -- that has the potential to create endless re-render loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put an unconditional state change in render. Because of that your render triggers a state change which triggers a re-render which again triggers a state change - An infinite loop.

You could put some sort of condition on which to trigger a state change for example:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){  
        super(props);  
        this.state = {name: "peter"}  
    }

    changename(){ this.setState({name:"sam"}); }
    
    render(){
      if(this.state.name==='peter')
        this.changename();

      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{this.state.name}</Text>
        </View>
      )
   } 
}
```